# How to define a bijection between a set of maps from a Cartesian product to an abelian group to a set of bilinear maps to that same group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $Q$,$R$ be sets and let $A$ be an abelian group. How to establish a bijection between the set of maps from the Cartesian product to the abelian group $Q\times R\to A$ and the set of bilinear maps $\mathbb{Z}Q\times\mathbb{Z}R\to A$? Does $\alpha:Q\times R\to A$ need to be extended to $\beta:\mathbb{Z}Q\times\mathbb{Z}R\to A$ ? I don't know how to approach this nor even how $\beta$ would be defined. For instance, say one has $Q=\{a,b,c\}$ and $R=\{d,e,f\}$, wouldn't elements of $Q$ and $R$ look like $9a-2b+5c$ and $2d+4e-8f$ (ie linear combinations) ? and the bilinear map would send this to $9a-2b+5c+2d+4e-8f$ ? I don't see how to show $\alpha(q,r)=\beta(q\times r)$ nor if this is even the right way to approach this. I know the universal property that allows one to extend (uniquely) a map from a given set to a group to a homomorphism to that group, but I'm not sure if this is relevant here. Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints.** If $\beta:\mathbb{Z}Q\times\mathbb{Z}R\to A$ is bilinear, you can obtain a map $f: Q\times R\to A$ by restriction since $Q\times R\subset \mathbb{Z}Q\times \mathbb{Z}R$.

Conversely, assume that you are given a map $f:Q\times R\to A$. What could be a bilinear map $\beta$ extending $f$ ?

You can rephrase this question as follows: knowing that $\beta(q,r)=f(q,r)$ for all $q\in Q$ and all $r\in R$, and given that $\beta$ must be $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear, what could be the value $\displaystyle\beta(\sum_{i=1}^n u_iq_i,\sum_{j=1}^m v_j r_j)$, where $u_i,v_j\in\mathbb{Z}$, $q_i\in Q,r_j\in R$ ?

Once you have write the missing two lines to answer this question, you should show that your answer yields indeed a bilinear map, and that the two constructions are inverse to each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though given that $\beta$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear, we have $\beta(u_iq_i,v_jr_j)=u_iv_j\beta(q_i,r_j)$. Doesn't this force $u_iv_j=1$ ?

Comment: No. I think your confusion comes from the notation you are using. I prefer to use the notation $e_q, q\in Q$ for the basis of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. Note that $Q$ is just a set, so thinking that $u.q=q+q+...+q$ has no sense . Even in the case $Q$ is an abelian group denoted additively , if you use my notation, you see that $u.e_q=e_q+e_q+...+e_q$ is different from $e_{u.q}=(e_q)^u$.

Comment: I'm confused by the sets- it is much simpler with groups (eg constructing a tensor product given a bilinear pairing). In particular the extension of the Cartesian product is where I'm stuck. I used your notation for $\beta(u_iq_i,v_jr_j)$ where I thought $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinearity allowed us to pull out the integer elements. Initially I was looking at it like that: for $Q=\{a,b,c\},R=\{d,e,f\}$, we want a bijection between $\{a,b,c\}\times\{d,e,f\}\to A$ and $\{x_1a,x_2b,x_3c\}\times\{x_4d,x_5e,x_6f\}\to A$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. So (similarly) there is (?) a trivial bijection with $x_i=1$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ in your comment ?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}Q$, sorry

Comment: Ah ok- like I said above though I used your notation for $\beta(u_iq_i,v_jr_j)$, and thinking $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinearity allows us to pull out the integer elements I got the false result; but initially I was looking at it like this: for $Q=\{a,b,c\},R=\{d,e,f\}$, we want a bijection between $\{a,b,c\}×\{d,e,f\}→A$ and $\{x_1a,x_2b,x_3c\}\times\{x_4d,x_5e,x_6f\}→A$ where $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. So we set $x_i=1$ (?).